# Excel: VBA referencing named range based on string variable

Tags: excel, range, named-ranges, vba

How do I reference/select a named range based on a string variable with the text being the name ranged name?

Example:

```
'Target is range variable which is set to cell that is double clicked.
'For this example lets say the cell value is "A1A"
Dim binName As String
binName = "B1" & Target(1).Value
MsgBox(binName) 'This displays "B1A1A" which is the name of the named range
Range(binName).Select 'I want to select the range with the name B1A1A
```

This gives me 
Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed 
on the last line of the above code.

I understand that Range() is looking for an object, but I dont know how to refer call a range name from a string variable.

Thank in advanced for any help.

Resolution Edit:
Per Davids recommendation below, I changed

```
Range(binName).Select
```

to

```
Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B1").Range(binName) 'where "B1" is the worksheet name
```

Comment: What is the scope of this name (Worksheet or Workbook)?

Comment: Also, why do you want to `Select` anything? [Hint: You like 99.9% of the time shouldn't `Select` anything.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: This error suggests that the Active worksheet does not contain the named range. If the range exists on another worksheet, this error should be expected.

Comment: According to Name Manager, the scope of the range is Workbook. Select may not be the best option. What I want is to move the users view to this range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have a Workbook scoped range that is still explicitly assigned to a single worksheet, which I gather is what you want (`Name` refers to some range on some other worksheet, etc.).

If you're doing this as UI, rather than `Select`  try using the following:

```
Application.GoTo Range(binName)
```

Or:

```
Application.GoTo [binName]
```

Tested, and seems to work even when a range is explicitly on another worksheet, `Application.GoTo` takes care of toggling to that sheet and selecting that range.

Comment: Thanks David! This worked to get me what I want. I did have to specify the sheet for this to work. Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B1").Range(binName)

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Evaluate(binName).Select`

Application Evaluate will evaluate a string and resolve the reference. It accepts strings as arguments, and doesnt need to resolve to a range (for example, `Application.Evaluate("10")` would result in a return of `10`).

For more information, check out the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel.

EDIT: Worth noting, this isnt properly error handled, so it could potentially return a `Nothing` reference, or an error, if the input string is not a valid named range.

**Additionally, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SomeRangeName").Select` should work (and does work) just fine. It is more likely that there is something wrong with the name of your range.**

Comment: I don't see any good reason to use `Evaluate` in this case, and it's probably more trouble than it's worth anyways. Assuming the string is valid and represents an actual `Name` in the active workbook, the problem is not in resolving the string -> string, it's more likely either the scope of the `Name` itself, or (related) which sheet is active at runtime. The use of `Target` suggests this is in a sheet's code module/event handler...

Comment: In all honesty, I just forgot all about using the String itself (since the OP was having an issue with it) and used `Evaluate` before realizing that chances are something is wrong with either the scope of the command, or the string itself. If I am not mistaken though, `Evaluate` should help with scope (since it is at the Application level), though I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you both. The code is activated on one sheet, and the named range is referring to a location on another sheet, but, according to the Name Manager, the scope of the named range is Workbook. Is there something else I can be missing?

Comment: Evaluate won't be able to resolve the scope -- if "B1A1A" is on a different worksheet, then it will evaluate as a string literal and then you get an Object Required error :)

Comment: I tried the Evaluate() code you provided. It is giving the same error, so I believe that you are correct that something else is wrong.

Comment: @DavidZemens Good to know. After I said it I read the documentation where they qualify the range and I figured I was wrong :).

Comment: @Bow Try using a different name, and also fully qualify your range references. It would be best to do something like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeSheetName").Range("SomeRangeName").Activate`. Try naming a cell "TestName" and then explicitly use that string.

Comment: @BrandonBarney I set binName = "TestRange", set a range name "TestRange", and qualified my range reference to: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B1").Range(binName).Activate where "B1" is the sheet name. I am now getting Run-time error '1004': Activate method of Range class failed. Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: @Bow you named a worksheet "B1"? That error is likely because either the range doesn't exist, or the target sheet isn't active